# Getting XML corruption after saving worksheet with added XSD Schema

Tags: xml, excel, xsd

I'm running into an issue after adding my XSD Schema file.  Once I close Excel, I can no longer open the file due to corruption.  I'm getting an "Undeclared XSD type" error in reference to PortNameType.  It is declared but in another XSD file that is included in the one I added to Excel via the include element (see below).

Main.xsd (file added to Excel)

```
...
<xsd:include schemaLocation="NamesSchema.xsd"></xsd:include>
...
<xsd:element name="port_name" type="PortNameType" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></xsd:element>
...
```

NamesSchema.xsd (included in Main.xsd)

```
...
<xsd:simpleType name="PortNameType1">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="COM1"></xsd:enumeration>
        <xsd:enumeration value="COM2"></xsd:enumeration>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:simpleType name="PortNameType2">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="RS485"></xsd:enumeration>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

</xsd:simpleType><xsd:simpleType name="PortNameType">
    <xsd:union memberTypes="PortNameType1 PortNameType2"></xsd:union>
</xsd:simpleType>
...
```

Can Excel handle the include element?

Also, can Excel handle the union element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that Excel cannot handle the include element.  Merged the 2 files into one and all is well.